# Backpacks for Field Recording 

Tags: kit-bag

Hi Guys,

Im looking for a backpack while field recording, So this is my setup - Rode Blimp, NTG3, 
SD MixPreD & Zoom H4n + I carry a Nikon D3100 with a 50mm, 18-55mm & a 70-300mm lens.

Any ideas for a backpack that would fits these stuff?

Kindly let me know if any use backpacks in the field.

Cheers!!!

Comment: have you found what you were looking for? have anyone considered a backpack allowed in cabin?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a huge Crumpler fan. The bags are basically indestructible, weather-proof, super comfortable, designed to safely house electronics, and they actually look good. And how can you not love a company who will give you a $200 backpack in exchange for a case of good beer? They do an annual Beer for Bags event at their stores.

I dropped one from a tree about 20 feet up directly into a disgusting swamp, and nothing got wet. It did take a trip through the washing machine to get the stink out of the bag, which didn't damage the bag at all either. Solid stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I´m also looking for something similar and i found the [Lowe DSLR Video Fastpack 350 AW](http://www.lowepro-deutschland.de/produkte/index.php?article_id=490&clang=0)

It seems like a good choice as it´s made for Videographers with extra audio mixers and the like. i´ll definetly give it a try, as it´s not that expensive and seems to be a very good product. I´ll definetly need space for my Canon 600D, my Tascam DR680, Zoom H4N (for Good and flexible Camera Audio), 2 Stands, and Battery stuff and also SD cards, Laptop, et cetera. 
You can also check the [Lowe Flipside 300](http://www.amazon.de/Lowepro-Flipside-300-SLR-Kamerarucksack-300-mm-Objektiv/dp/B000YA33DC/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_S_nC?ie=UTF8&colid=3IJDF9F62FW6M&coliid=I18EPATGJFE9EY)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the backpacks that are designed to carry still/DSLR cameras. Many of them are configurable and could potentially hold all the gear you're talking about. Can't think of any brands other than [CineBags](http://www.cinebags.com/hdpackpack.html) at the moment

Comment: thanks shaun - i saw the kata bags site & it had some cool backpack to checkout 

Answer (score 0):

I want to get [this one](http://products.lowepro.com/product/Pro-Trekker%20600%20AW,2167.htm).
Might be a bit expensive, but it's great for hiking and the AW 600 should be big enough for the rather huge Røde blimp and your other gear?
It can also fit a tripod, boompole or something on the outside.

Comment: Thats a good one, but have a look @ this one buddy
http://www.kata-bags.com/pro-v-610-pl-hdv-backpack?tab=presentation

Check out the interior dimension of the lowepro bag that you've mentioned its a bit small compared to this kata bag + kata's cool looking as well.

This one could easily fits the blimp & other other stuff - im gonna buy this one.

Comment: Cool, glad you found what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

I always liked the Mountainsmith camera line: http://www.mountainsmith.com/products.asp?categoryId=13

Currently I am using their Kit Cube insert inside of an REI Quantum Daypack (http://www.rei.com/product/809171/rei-quantum-daypack) to carry audio, video and camera gear, and it works fantastic.  May not carry your blimp, but everything else will fit nice and snug and padded...plus a laptop too!

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at the Tamrac Expedition 8. http://www.tamrac.com/5588.htm

It's designed primarily as a camera bag for multiple long, heavy lenses etc. I carry a rode blimp inside it with a plethora of other things (along with a boompole on the outside and also a tripod inside too) it's built like a tank, extremely well made, waterproof and, even when heavy, feels fine to carry over long distances. It's a big bag though and somewhat expensive. Apart from the AW 600 mentioned in a previous post, it was the only real option I found that fitted the rode blimp and all my other gear. It's not cheap but there are second-hand options around if you're willing to hunt around.

Answer (score 0):

I like and own a few different LowePro backpack bags & especially like the AW models that have a rain cover built in to the base of them...

http://www.lowepro.com

Answer (score 0):

Hey Bala, i'm in a same situation looking for a trekking backpack where i can fit the rode and other stuff so i wonder, how the kata bag worked out for you?
A picture will be very helpful too, shukriyaa!

Comment: Hey Fumei,

Here is a link - check this out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVC1WghMH3M

The bag in the video is a lengthier one so i guess it should fit the blimp. I have ordered this one - i still am expecting this one.

Best of Luck.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Hei i think the best thing you can get for under 200,- is the Calumet BP1500. Plenty space for blimp, mic, recorder, cablex etc. and a laptop.

Comment: Hello, does this bag fit the rode blimp - i checked out calumets website - the internal height is 20 inches - im just curious to know - do u use this 
cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I use a belt mounted pouch (similar to this: http://www.combatsportsupply.com/voodootacticalmolledumppouch.aspx) that fits the Zoom perfectly - as well as having side pockets for carrying mics/looping cables through. This is great for both boom swinging and field recording as it allows for great mobility and means at any time you can be recording within seconds. For the shotgun/blimp you can just clip a large carabiner to your belt and loop the blimp handle in there.

Answer (score 0):

Vanguard Up-Rise should do the trick. The 48 model would hold all of that and then some.

I own an Up-Rise 46 and I have a Canon 5D Mark II, 24-105L, 85 f/1.8, Sigma 35 f/1.4 and 135 f/2L I carry around with me,

plus a laptop. ;)